# What is the format of target pane/window for tmux?

Tags: tmux

Many of the commands in tmux deal with a target and source window/pane and I know sometimes you can supply things like `1:2` to specify pane 2 of window 1, however now I'm looking at more advanced usage, sessions now seem to fit in to this aswell.

I constantly forget the syntax and I can't find detailed information about it in [the documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/tmux.1.html#contenttoc11).

Could anyone help shed some light?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your answer is hidden in an example inside a text about target-pane :

> target-pane (or src-pane or dst-pane) may be a pane ID or takes a similar
>       form to target-window but with the optional addition of a period followed
>       by a pane index or pane ID, for example: ‘mysession:mywindow.1’.  If the
>       pane index is omitted, the currently active pane in the specified window
>       is used.  The following special tokens are available for the pane index:

You can test it by creating a background/daemonized tmux session named $SESSION like so :

```
tmux new-session -d -s $SESSION
```

you can monitor this session in another terminal by using :

```
tmux attach-session -t $SESSION
```

and then using this command from the "non tmux" terminal

```
tmux send-keys -t $SESSION:0.42
```

and then if the pane 42 doesnt exist, tmux will complain.

Now by using a test string, like so :

```
tmux send-keys -t $SESSION:0.42 "test" C-m
```

You can pinpoint the exact pane interactively if you don't know the exact pane number that you want.

On a side note, you can display pane numbers inside a tmux session by entering (listed in the key bindings session of the documentation you linked)

```
    C-b q           Briefly display pane indexes.
```

Comment: So when the OP says "`1:2` to specify pane 2 of window 1", it's a misunderstanding, because `1:2` specifies window 2 of session 1. Pane 2 of window 1 (of current session) would be `:1.2`. Right?

Comment: It looks like so, i can't confirm right now that the "current session" is implied by not using anything before :1.2, but if you take the good habit of giving all your sessions a name it definitely works as expected (and protects bad interactions between scripts that run tmux non-interactively, or at least unattended)